# How did Voldemort lose his body?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Lily's protection bounced `Avada Kedavara` spell back at Voldemort. Right?

According to [HP Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Killing_Curse#Nature),

> When the curse hits a living, organic target it invariably kills them
>   **without injury**.

How did the `Avada Kedavara` curse *vaporize* Voldemort's body?

Comment: Excellent question!

Comment: Maybe it's the effect when you are (attempted to be) killed by Avada Kedavra but you have horcruxes protecting your Soul?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Lily's protection bounced Avada Kedavara spell back at Voldemort. Right?

Wrong. :)

The spell did not bounce back as:

- During the Battle of Hogwarts, Harry puts a sacrificial protection on everyone, but Voldemort's spells do not bounce back, they simply are not binding.
- Had the spell bounced back there would have been no explosion, as you say.

So what happened? We see for instance during the duel between Dumbledore and Voldemort what happens when a Killing Curse doesn't hit living matter: it releases energy, which destroyed the stone sculptures.

So the spell hit the love protection, and was diverted by it. Some energy leaked out, as the ricochet of a bullet leaves a mark on the wall.

This curse was very special for Voldemort, as it was the accomplishment of the prophecy and the creation of a horcrux. He probably put a monstrous amount of power in the curse which is already the most potent one. So it made a huge boom, and Big V was vaporized...

Comment: That first bulletpoint is irrelevant. Voldemort killed Lily before he tried to kill Harry. I'd also be interested to see a quote or some other canon information to support the creation of a horcrux being part of the plan, because I don't remember anything like that at all.

Comment: Agree with @AnthonyGrist - Horcrux was not intentional

Comment: No. But I remember Dumbledore saying Voldemort intended to create a horcruxe (the sixth and last one)

Comment: I always thought the unintended seventh horcrux (Harry) was created at the moment Voldemort killed **Lily**, not Harry. Dumbledore said (someone back me up here please) that when Lily was murdered, Voldemort's soul split once more and latched onto the closest living thing---Harry. So Harry became a horcrux before Voldemort attacked him as a baby. *Then* Voldemort cast AK on Harry, which backfired.

Comment: He intended to create a Horcrux, yes, but as far as can be inferred from canon, Horcrux creation happens **after** the killing itself. Killing splits the soul; afterwards, you perform the spell to use that splitting to your own advantage. Killing Harry would not in itself create a Horcrux.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong! What happened was when Lily died sacrificing herself for your son she unintentionally placed the power of love over Harry. This is the one thing Voldemort could not do, so after killing Lily Voldemort could not kill Harry because of love. However the reason Voldemort lost his power was because yes he had 6 horcrux's already and also because of love. The love took the last remaining piece of soul from him and latched onto Harry. A body can still live without a soul though, as said in HP3 but there was no confirmation that he did lose his body. It only said he lost his powers.

Comment: What do you mean "wrong"? Who's wrong? Are you attempting to reply to or comment on one of the answers here?

Comment: @Mooz - The OP asked "right?". The accepted answer starts the same way.

Comment: 1) Voldemort did not already have six Horcruxes: he had five. He intended to make the sixth after killing Harry, but he never got that far. 2) The bit of Voldemort's soul that latched on to Harry was not the final bit—the ‘main’ bit was still Voldemort's own consciousness from which he was reborn in _GoF_. 3) Lily did not die sacrificing herself for my son; I don't have a son.